# jquery mobile or HTML5 app

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I'm trying to build an application which must be cross platform and must work like a native android app. I have built apps on phonegap but never i have got a native app like feeling. Is there is a framework or anything of that sort which might help me to achieve this?
So far i have used

- Jquery mobile, phonegap, appcelerator, trigger.io

Any advice suggestions and help are welcome.
And also i got this feeling or need when i came across this `http://www.aldomatic.com/jqm/fb-menu-style/index.html` and i wanted to build a facebook like menu which feels more like native but it should be HTML5 based app.

Comment: Well, it seems that you've already tried the common stuff and currently there is no alternative to make your app feel more "native". The feeling is still browser dependent and as far as I know there is no conversion of your jquery code into native code possible. Phonegap is using a webview and just provides some native functions it can access and that's IMO the best way to do it.

Comment: @gulty Well, ok. So to build a web service similar to facebook phonegap is not a worthy option?

Comment: Of course it is. Facebook only dropped that because of some scrolling issue and of course to improve the speed. Phonegap is still a good option and it's working better and better on new devices. But for a solution for most devices (like iphone 3) web-based apps will be too slow.

Comment: according to [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-making-of-fastbook-an-html5-love-story/) facebook did their HTML5 app just wrong..

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes I saw the story, but i would still like to go for a native one.. the feel is what matters when a user has paid so much for a smartphone like NOTE 2 or any other high end model. don't you think so?

Comment: @Mirage I would always go for a native app, especially android. But I wanted to get the facts right.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I cant think of any mobile web framework that will provide you full Android look and feel. There's only iOS look a like framework called [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/).

Best thing you can do is stick with jQuery Mobile and use a theme that has a closest resemblance to a native Android look and feel.

There are 2 of them, some older and some newer:

1. https://github.com/enathu/jqmobile-android-holo-light-theme (Android 4 look)
2. https://github.com/jjoe64/jquery-mobile-android-theme (Android 2.X look)

Also jQuery mobile 1.3 has a sliding panel you showed us in your link. Even better, sliding panel used in your link is the jQuery Mobile panel.

Comment: The android holo theme look, i meant the first link looks pretty cool. KendoUI seems to solve my IOS probs. But i have to build the similar stuff on android. So, android seems to be a problem.

Comment: You can still make it with some additional customization, take a look at this link: http://teusink.blogspot.com/2012/09/android-holo-theme-for-jquery-mobile-111.html there's an additional link at a bottom, it is a Android app build with a jQM and Holo theme, it has a real native look and feel. Only real problems are input elements but you can easily customize them by your self. Unfortunately there's a thing you can't fix and that is a slight jQM sluggishness, but this is a problem of every mobile web framework.

Comment: There's also a IBM Worklight 5.0.5, it has built in support for jQM apps with a corresponding Android/iOS themes, here's an example: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_jquery_mobile_with_worklight_5_0_0?lang=en . I hope all this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found this one

http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/nativedroid-free-theme-jquery-mobile-1-3/

it's the closest to native android theme i have found.

Hope it helps!